# How to remove margin set at the top and bottom of ComboBox items list in an UWP application

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

In my UWP application, I use a ComboBox and I try to suppress the margin that is placed at the top and the bottom of the ComboBox Items.

By looking at the [ComboBox style template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299116.aspx), it seems that this margin is piloted by the following value : *ComboBoxDropdownContentMargin*, which is set at 0,7,0,7.

I have created a new style for my ComboBox as follows, but it does not work at all (my ComboBox disappear). I tried lots of other solutions but with no results too.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Popup>
                            <Border>
                                <ScrollViewer>
                                    <ItemsPresenter Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

I am quite new in UWP/XAML coding, so I apologize if my question seems ridiculous, but can anyone tell me how I can suppress margin placed by the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new style and changing the `ItemsPresenter` is right. But when you override the 'Template' setter it will update the whole setter, the code above only left the `ItemsPresenter` element but other elements are gone so you cannot see the combobox. Complete this style and remain others same with the default style, then it will work. Please update the style as follows:

```
 <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                            Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeMargin}"
                            FontWeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeFontWeight}"
                            x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                            FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}"
                            Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <Border
                            x:Name="Background"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                        <Border
                            x:Name="HighlightBackground"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
                            BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Opacity="0" />
                        <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
                                Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseHighBrush}"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" />
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <FontIcon
                            x:Name="DropDownGlyph"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0,10,10,10"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                            FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                            FontSize="12"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                            Glyph="&#xE0E5;"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                            <Border
                                x:Name="PopupBorder"
                                Margin="0,-1,0,-1"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}"
                                BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeHighBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderThickness}">
                                <ScrollViewer
                                    x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                    MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownContentMinWidth}"
                                    Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                    BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}"
                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                    HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                    IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                    IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                    IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                    VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                    VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near"
                                    VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle"
                                    ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                    <ItemsPresenter Margin="0"/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundAltMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1" />
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="FocusedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1" />
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Duration="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <SplitOpenThemeAnimation
                                            ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                            OffsetFromCenter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset}"
                                            OpenedLength="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight}"
                                            OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <SplitCloseThemeAnimation
                                            ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                            OffsetFromCenter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset}"
                                            OpenedLength="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight}"
                                            OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

You can also just edit a copy of the default style, the XAML designer will generate all the default style for you and you just need update the one you want. For how to generate the default style, you can choose the Combobox control-> right click->Edit template->Edit a copy, details please see: [image: screen shot]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's fully answers my question